# Cómo obtener solo la primera coincidencia en un tabla con SQL?

Tags: sql

Buenas estoy tratando de mostrar los resultados que no coinciden de 2 columnas, el problema con la consulta que armé es que, cuando algo hace match se lleva todos los match y solo estaria necesitando que haga match el primero que pueda.

La consulta como está ahora es esta:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM TABLEX AS A
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM TABLEX AS B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN2)
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que tengo:

INPUT:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   6000        0
1   1000        0
1   2000        0
1   1000        0
1   0         1000
1   3000      3000
1   0         2000
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
1   0         6000
```

OUTPUT ACTUAL:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
```

OUTPUT ESPERADO:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   1000        0
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
```

Qué podria agregarle a la query para corregir esto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podras hacer toda la pregunta en español?

Comment: has probado con un select first? SELECT FIRST(column_name) FROM table_name;

Comment: La sintaxis del sql que necesitas depende del motor de base de datos en el que la vayas a ejecutar. Que motor de base de datos estas usando: SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL ?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener la primer pareja que coincida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385098/obtener-la-primer-pareja-que-coincida)

Comment: Esta pregunta está repetida, ambas las hizo el mismo usuario con dos horas de diferencia (aproximadamente). La referida por @jachguate es la otra y además tiene una respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Para SqlServer:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
  FROM TABLEX AS A
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEX AS B
                   WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN2);
```

Para MySQL y PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
  FROM TABLEX AS A
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEX AS B
                   WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN2)
LIMIT 1;
```

Para ORACLE:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
  FROM TABLEX AS A
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLEX AS B
                   WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN2)
   AND ROWNUM<=1;
```