# Obtener la primer pareja que coincida

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de mostrar los resultados que no tienen coincidencia entre 2 columnas.

En otras palabras, estoy tratando de formar parejas de la columna 1 y 2 y mostrar como resultado los que no tengan pareja.

En el resultado aparecen los casos de 4000 y 5000 porque ninguno tiene pareja lo cual esta bien.

El problema es que para el caso de 1000 se repite 2 veces en la columna 1.

Solo necesitaría formar una pareja y como queda un caso de 1000 solo mostrarlo en el resultado.

La query como esta ahora es esta:

```
SELECT ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM TABLEX AS A
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM TABLEX AS B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN2)
```

INPUT ACTUAL:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   6000        0
1   1000        0
1   2000        0
1   1000        0
1   0         1000
1   3000      3000
1   0         2000
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
1   0         6000
```

OUTPUT ACTUAL:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
```

OUTPUT ESPERADO:

```
ID  COLUMN1     COLUMN2
-------------------------------
1   1000        0
1   4000        0
1   0         5000
```

¿Qué podría agregarle a la query para corregir esto?

Comment: No entiendo la lógica ¿Por qué aparece el 4000 y el 5000? ¿Como defines "el primero"? Ahí no hay nada que defina orden.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Con el input actual, el query que muestras solo produce la fila `1, 4000, 0`. Pero, sobre todo, no explicas bien como conseguir el resultado que quieres... y no ayuda que el verbo _matchear_ no existe... supongo que quieres decir que coincidan, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Asumiendo que con la expresión _no matchean_ quieres decir que no tienen coincidencia, puedo entender que 4000 forma parte del resultado esperado porque no hay coincidencias en la columna 2,  pero ¿por qué 1000 es parte del resultado esperado? 6000 tiene un patron similar que el de 1000 y no es parte de lo esperado. Me parece contradictorio. Será necesario mejorar el planteamiento. Ya esta pregunta te la cerraron una vez y no hay mucha diferencia entre la cerrada y esta.

Comment: gracias ahi trato de acomodar mejor pregunta

Comment: Enredas con lo de *obtener primer pareja que coincida* en tu titulo, que no es lo que pretendes en tu explicación. Deseas descartar pares repetidos en las columnas 1 y 2 y quedarte con aquellos que no se repiten. O al menos es lo que se entiende de tu explicación. ¿Cierto?

Comment: Hace una gran diferencia el nuevo enfoque que le diste a la pregunta, ahora si me quedó claro. De hecho me recuerda al trabajo que se hace durante una revisión de cuentas de contabilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.ID,B.ID) ID
    , ISNULL(A.[columna],0) COLUMN1
    , ISNULL(B.[columna],0) COLUMN2
FROM (
        SELECT ID, COLUMN1  [columna], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN1 ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC) AS RowNum FROM TABLEX WHERE COLUMN1 != 0
    ) A
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ID, COLUMN2  [columna], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN2 ASC) AS RowNum FROM TABLEX WHERE COLUMN2 != 0
    ) B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.[columna]=B.[columna] AND A.RowNum=B.RowNum
WHERE A.[columna] IS NULL OR B.[columna] IS NULL
```

Genero dos subconsultas a la misma tabla donde regreso el id, la columna (1,2) y con rownumber lo particiono para que los numere en base a la columna.

De una consulta me regresa esto.

```
ID          columna     RowNum
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1000        1
1           1000        2
1           2000        1
1           3000        1
1           4000        1
1           6000        1
```

Para el join lo hago Full Outer Join para validar por id, columna y el RowNum, con lo que hace un cruce y me regresa todo, lo que coincide y lo que no.

```
ID          COLUMN1     COLUMN2     RowNum               RowNum
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           1000        1000        1                    1
1           1000        0           2                    NULL
1           2000        2000        1                    1
1           3000        3000        1                    1
1           4000        0           1                    NULL
1           6000        6000        1                    1
1           0           5000        NULL                 1
```

Y por ultimo en el where dejo todo lo que no tenga pareja ó que sea null.

```
ID          COLUMN1     COLUMN2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1000        0
1           4000        0
1           0           5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo, para encontrar las filas que no tienen coincidencia, comenzaría numerando en dos *CTE* las apariciones de cada número, tanto en la `column1`, como en la `column2`.

Luego, hacer `join` de las filas ya numeradas, me permite encontrar las coincidencias. De hecho, un `full outer join` me permitiría, encontrar las coincidencias para descartarlas, y quedarme con los que no tienen coincidencia.

En código:

```
Numeracion1 as (
select   ID
       , COLUMN1
       , COLUMN2
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID, COLUMN1 order by (select null)) Numero1
  from tablex
 where COLUMN1 != 0
   and COLUMN1 != COLUMN2 
)
,
Numeracion2 as (
select   ID
       , COLUMN1
       , COLUMN2
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID, COLUMN2 order by (select null)) Numero2
  from tablex
 where COLUMN2 != 0
   and COLUMN1 != COLUMN2 
)
select   coalesce(n1.id, n2.id) id
       , coalesce(n1.column1, n2.column1) column1
       , coalesce(n1.COLUMN2, n2.column2) column2
  from Numeracion1 n1
       full outer join Numeracion2 n2 on n2.id = n1.id and n1.COLUMN1 = n2.COLUMN2 and n1.Numero1 = n2.Numero2
 where n1.Numero1 is null
    or n2.Numero2 is null
```

Con tus datos de entrada, me devuelve:

```
id          column1     column2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1000        0
1           4000        0
1           0           5000

(3 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-08-26T15:33:12.7123145-06:00
```